# JAXB unmarshaling with namespaces.. how?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Say my valid xml looks something like below:

```
<A xmlns="something">
   <B>4</B>
</A>
```

My code is like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter //from lombok
public class Data{

@XmlElement(name = "B")
private String b;

public Data(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public Data() {
}
// Getter/setter generated by lombok.
}
```

How do I get this to work? If my xml tag has some associated elements like 'xmlns' above, the JAXB unmarshaller throws exceptions.

I'm doing this for the first time, so I really don't have a clue about JAXB, unmarshaling, etc. I'm floundering. :)
Any help would be good.

**EDIT**
StackTrace:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"something", local:"A"). Expected elements are <{}B>,<{}A>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
at ...
```

Comment: Could you post your code and the exception?

Comment: Doesn't the `b` field need getter and setter methods?

Comment: It does, I am using lombok. :) The @Getter annotation is from lombok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a namespace in your xml document, you need to have that in your jaxb annotations as well.

E.g. like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A", namespace="something")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data{
```

Comment: Okay.. Another question, what if I have multiple 'namespaces'? Like <A xmlns="something" xmlns:xsi="something else" xsi:type = "another"></>

Answer (score 3):

From `XmlRootElement`'s sources:

> ```
> public @interface XmlRootElement {
>     /**
>      * namespace name of the XML element.
>      * <p>
>      * If the value is "##default", then the XML namespace name is derived
>      * from the package of the class ( {@link XmlSchema} ). If the
>      * package is unnamed, then the XML namespace is the default empty
>      * namespace.
>      */
>     String namespace() default "##default";
>      // else of file
> ```

You should also keep in mind this rule also apply to most JAXB annotations, so you need to specify the root element **and also other elements** with namespace explicitly given, like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace="something", name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter //from lombok
public class Data{
    @XmlElement(namespace="something", name = "B") // <-- mind this
    private String b;

    public Data(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public Data() {
    }
    // Getter/setter generated by lombok.
}
```

If you don't, it will expect, supposing your `Data` is in `org.example` package, some elements within namespace `org.example` **as long as you have `@XmlSchema(elementFormDefault=QUALIFIED)`**, or it will expect elements in the default namespace.

Comment: Oh okay! What if I have multiple different namespaces?

Comment: Then you change the namespace property of corresponding `XmlRootElement`, `XmlElement`, `XmlAttribute`, etc..

Comment: I mean, I have <A xmlns="something" xsi:type="somethingelse"></A>

Comment: I assume your `xsi` refers to XMLSchema-Instance namespace. Then you will add a String field and annotate it with `@XmlAttribute(namespace=java.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI, name="type")` to get the value you set in the `xsi:type` attribute.

Comment: Oh! So namespaces are all some elements already defined as a part of the xml format. Okay then. II didn't know that. Thank you very much! I will mark this as the answer once I get my unmarshaling to work. I'll come back here if I can't make it work.

Comment: Yes, namespace is quite an essential part of the XML standard, since all other XML related technique depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add an @XmlAttribute to A (alogn with the corresponding getter/setter)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter //from lombok
public class Data{

@XmlAttribute(name="xmln")
String attr;
@XmlElement(name = "B")
private String b;

public Data(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}

   public Data() {
 }
// Getter/setter generated by lombok.
    public String getAttr(){
    return attr;
    }
    public void setAttr(String attr){
    this.attr = attr;
  }
  }
```

EDIT: This does not answer the question because the question is about xml namespaces and not attributes.

Comment: This post fully demonstrates how you don't understand what xml is.

Comment: This isn't it, @dsp_user

Comment: Yes, I thought you were interested in xml attributes in general, and not in xml namespaces. Sorry

Comment: If you did inspect the exception message you will quickly come to know the problem is that the qualified name doesn't match, not there is a missing attribute that cause the unmarshaller to complain.

Comment: Well, I was hasty. We all do that sometimes, don't we? (the exception mentioning the url is quite revealing)